# Непонятное сравнение в php

Tags: php

Изучаю php и не понимаю как так получается. Сравниваю 2 числа и результат true.

```
var_dump(9 == 011);
```

Причём если будет `09` то получаю ошибку, а `011` интерпритатор пропускает

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду читать про типы в php

Comment: Вы ещё js не смотрели ))

Answer (score 7):

Потому, что интерпретатор преобразует `011` в восьмиричную систему, а это как раз `9`.
А `09` php не может преобразовать ни к одной, доступной ему системе.